# ObjectiveC: NSScanner scanDouble problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my iPhone app I am trying to understand if a string is a valid number or not, the code below works most of the time but when I have a value starting with number and ends with text it wrongly returns "true" e.g "34rty"

```
if([[NSScanner scannerWithString:value] scanDouble:NULL] ){
     val=[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value doubleValue]];
}
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanDouble` return via a reference.

```
NSString *string = @"34rty";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
double doubleValue;
[scanner scanDouble:&doubleValue];
NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:doubleValue];
NSLog(@"doubleValue: %f", doubleValue);
NSLog(@"doubleNumber: %@", doubleNumber);
```

NSLog output:

```
doubleValue: 34.000000
doubleNumber: 34
```

You will have to scan up to the number if there is preceding text.

As @Benjamin says, a RegEx may be a better option for just checking.

Comment: tnx but I dont wanna bother with downloading regexlibraris importing and using expressions just for thsi task..that should not be complicated

Comment: ok this regex worked but still think its a bit overkill   "^(?:|0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?$"

Comment: RegEx it part of iOS 4 but is not necessarily easy to use.

Comment: I used RegexKitLite.h is that a problem?

Comment: No problem, that is a fine package.

Answer (score -2):

NSScanner stops at the first matching character. So it finds '3', returns positive as it did scan a double, and then stops running. It doesn't check every character.

A REGEX check is a better choice for this purpose.

Comment: `scanDouble` does not stop on the first matching character.